# findChild does not find menu just added to a QMenuBar

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Here is my code snippet:

```
void MainWindow::on_TestButton_triggered()
{
    QMenu *m = menuBar()->addMenu("TestMenu");

    auto *found = menuBar()->findChild<QMenu *>("TestMenu");
    if ( !found )
        MessageBox(NULL, "not found", "s", MB_OK);
}
```

It always produces the MessageBox.  What can I do instead to get a pointer (or other handle) of an existing menu in the bar?

The ultimate goal of this is to be able to find and delete menus that were added in a different code block, so "just use `m`" would not be a solution.  I have a workable solution by maintaining an external vector of the return value of `addMenu` but would like something a bit more elegant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

findChild uses the objectName to do the search but in your case QMenu does not have an objectName, so the solution is to set the objetctName:

```
QMenu *m = menuBar()->addMenu("TestMenu")
m->setObjetctName("TestMenu");
```